# What is Wireshark and WinPcap?

Tags: wcf, wireshark, winpcap

I'm working with a WCF service I wrote a few years back, which uses TCP.  It's causing me problems saying, “…the target machine actively refused” my attempting to connect to it.  I've no idea why the target machine (our Windows 2003 Server) should now be actively refusing my connecting to it, when just last week it was all hunky-dory.  I've asked on the MSDN forums, and was told to run something called Wireshark.  I've never heard of it.  Is Wireshark sort of like Fiddler, only including other protocols besides HTTP?

And another thing.  I've downloaded Wireshark and have started to install it.  Early on in the installation it informed me that it wants to update something called WinPcap.  I've never heard of that, either.  I've done another search on that and have found on Wikipedia and see that it is the Windows version of pcap, which stands for packet capture.  And according to Wireshark's website, whatever version of WinPcap currently on my system is, “… annoying bugs …” and version 4.1.2 of WinPcap fixes them.  OK, that's nice and all, but frankly satisfying Wireshark's needs alone isn't what I'm here to do.  I'd like to know what impact replacing WinPcap will have on my system.  What else relies upon WinPcap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wireshark is a tool used to analyze network traffic.  [Win]Pcap is a dependency for providing that functionality, as you found out.  If you have other tools that require packet capturing they may use pcap.  Generally, there *shouldn't* be anything else on your system using Pcap, but we have no way of knowing what is on your system.....

Using Wireshark to diagnose a connection problem with your application is generally overkill.  I would suggest checking that your application correctly binds to a hostname and interface correctly, that the port is actively opened by using another tool like netstat, etc before you go digging around in packet captures.

You might try something like opening up a command prompt window and using:
netstat -p tcp -a

You should see a list of all TCP connections and opened ports on your machine.  If you don't see an appropriate port that your application should have opened (or a weird IP) then you know there's something up with your application.  You can also check the Windows Firewall and add exceptions if you need them.

Comment: I've issued the netstat command that you suggested.  It does list different IP addresses and ports, being used on my machine, using TCP.  However, I don't specify anything in my PC, concerning which port on my machine to use.  I do specify in the App.Config file which port to use on the server, in the binding section.

Comment: You can use the same command on the server to verify that the expected port is opened and listening for new connections.  If it is there but you still can't connect, you want to check Windows Firewall and/or your application settings for IP/Host binding.
If it is NOT there, you will want to verify that your application is working, has correct permissions and is opening the port correctly.

Comment: Thank you, esnyder, that was a good idea.  I've just run that netstat command on the server, and it doesn't look to me as though it's listening on TCP port 9000.  I think looked into the server's Services (my WCF service has to run as an app hosted by a Windows Service, which I also wrote), and that service is listed there, but it isn't in a Started state.  I tried starting it, but it won't start, or it starts and shuts down immediately, which it shouldn't do.  The Windows Firewall is turned off on the server.

Comment: Check your application log for possible errors.  You can also use sc query from the command line to find out more about the service.

Comment: Finally found out what the problem was. I'd forgotten you have to take an extra step when dealing with a Windows 2003  or 2003 R2 Server.  You've got to use the InstallUtil.exe utility to install the Windows service which hosts the WCF service, which I was doing.  The step I'd forgotten about was going into the Windows Services applet and actually starting the service.  After that there was an issue with maxReceivedMessageSize and maxBufferSize not being the same, but that was a quick fix after resolving the TCP issue.

Answer (score 2):

As esnyder says, Wireshark is a network analyzer, similar to, for example, [Sniffer](http://www.netscout.com/products/enterprise/Sniffer_Portable_Analyzer/Pages/default.aspx) or [OmniPeek](http://www.wildpackets.com/products/omnipeek_network_analyzer) or [Microsoft's Network Monitor](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933741).